# How to safely set a void* to a specific address c++

Tags: c++, memory, void-pointers

I've read a couple articles suggesting not to cast int to void* or void* to int. I need to set a pointer to a specific address and the only way I know how is...

```
#define MEMORY_ALLOC_START_ADDR 0x7E00
void * address = (void*)MEMORY_ALLOC_START_ADDR;
```

Is this safe and 'proper'? I only need to cast to a void* not vice versa. The only other way i can think to assign it would be using extended inline assembly. I'm asking so I don't run into unexpected problems down the road.

Comment: How do you validate that your fixed memory address is correct everytime. The code looks ok but i do not think it is good idea to use some fixed number at the place of address.

Comment: Are you doing some kind of microcontroller or SOC device programming? I suspect those articles may have been written for the perspective of 'most' developers, not taking into account some kinds of low level embedded systems that don't have an MMU, for example.

Perhaps you might post the links, for context?

Comment: @MantoshKumar Real mode instead of protected. I don't have a choice but to use a fixed address

Comment: @AndrewMcDonnell It's actually a bootloader before switching to protected mode. Ill see if I can find the links again but I think they were referring to a user mode application environment. Give me a second to search my history for the links

Comment: @user3141117: If you know that your fixed address is valid one, your code is ok.

Comment: Real world example: coreboot does something similar - http://lxr.linux.no/#coreboot+r6637/src/boot/selfboot.c ( - although it gets the unsigned integer value for the casted address from parsing stuff), but you can see a cast from a u32 to void* near the end of the file...

Answer (score 4):

That should be fine, as long as that address is valid on whatever system you're targeting.

In general, converting between `void*` and `int` can cause failures when the two types aren't the same size (like on x64 where `void*` is 64-bits and `int` is only 32 - converting a `void*` to `int` there will lose half the value).

Comment: Isn't `reinterpret_cast<>` preferred in C++ over C-style casts?